# Data from Django form doesn't get saved to MySQL table

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to save data, collected via a Django form, to the DB. The page is designed to first ask user for an input, based on which a list is generated. I am trying to save values corresponding to these generated items. But this data, while I see it in the POST request, just doesn't get saved. I am assuming the error is in my Save logic, but I just cannot find it out.

I have the views defined to save this, and also the relevant URLs. The Django logs show no error, and there are none when I look into the DB error log. Here's how my code looks like:

Model

```
class MonthlySheet(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField()
    year = models.IntegerField()
    org_name = models.ForeignKey(Establishment, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    wages = models.IntegerField()
    gross = models.IntegerField()
    total_work_days = models.IntegerField()
    present_days = models.IntegerField()
    calc_twelve = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    calc_eight_three_three = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    calc_diff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    calc_point_seven_five = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('monthly_sheet_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = f"{self.month}.{self.year}"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

View:

```
class AddMonthlySheetView(FormView):
    template_name = 'add_monthlysheet.html'
    form_class = CustomMonthlySheetForm
    model = MonthlySheet

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        last_month, year, total_work_days = set_previous_month()
        context['last_month'] = last_month
        context['year'] = year
        context['total_work_days'] = total_work_days
        context['establishments'] = Establishment.objects.all()
        establishment_id = self.request.POST.get('org_name')  # Use POST instead of GET
        if establishment_id:
            employees = get_employees_from_establishment(establishment_id)
            context['employees'] = employees
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        month = form.cleaned_data['month']
        year = form.cleaned_data['year']
        org_name = form.cleaned_data['org_name']

        employees = form.cleaned_data['employee']
        wages = form.cleaned_data['wages']
        gross = form.cleaned_data['gross']
        total_work_days = form.cleaned_data['total_work_days']
        present_days = form.cleaned_data['present_days']

        for employee in employees:
            MonthlySheet.objects.create(
                month=month,
                year=year,
                org_name=org_name,
                employee=employee,
                wages=wages,
                gross=gross,
                total_work_days=total_work_days,
                present_days=present_days
            )

        return redirect('employee_list')

def monthly_sheet_detail(request, pk):
    monthly_sheet = get_object_or_404(MonthlySheet, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'monthly_sheet_detail.html', {'monthly_sheet': monthly_sheet})
```

Form:

```
class CustomMonthlySheetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    month = forms.IntegerField()
    year = forms.IntegerField()
    org_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Establishment.objects.all(), required=True)
    employee = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.filter(isactive=True), required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    wages = forms.IntegerField()
    gross = forms.IntegerField()
    total_work_days = forms.IntegerField()
    present_days = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = MonthlySheet
        fields = ('month', 'year', 'org_name', 'employee', 'wages', 'gross', 'total_work_days', 'present_days')
```

HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add Monthly Sheet{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Monthly Sheet</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="wide-seperator"></div>
      <form method="POST" id="select-unit">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-field">
            <label for="month">For the Month of:</label>
            <input type="number" id="month" name="month" value="{{ last_month }}" required readonly>
            <label for="year">in Year:</label>
            <input type="number" id="year" name="year" value="{{ year }}" required readonly>
          </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-field">
              <label for="org_name">Establishment:</label>
              <select name="org_name" id="org_name" required>
                <option value="">---Select Establishment---</option>
                {% for establishment in establishments %}
                  <option value="{{ establishment.id }}"> {{ establishment.org_name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
              <input type="submit" value="Show">
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="monthlysheet-list-container">  
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="{{ last_month }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="{{ year }}">
    {% if employees %}
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>UAN</th>
            <th>Wages</th>
            <th>Gross</th>
            <th>Total Days</th>
            <th>Present Days</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for employee in employees %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ employee.uan }}</td>
            <input type="hidden" name="employee" value="{{ employee.name }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="org_name" value="{{ employee.org_name.id }}">
            <td><input type="number" name="wages" value="{{ employee.wages }}" required></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="gross" value="{{ employee.gross }}" required></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="total_work_days" value="{{ total_work_days }}" required></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="present_days" value="{{ present_days }}" required></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save Data">
  </form>
</div>    

{% endblock %}
```

URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add_monthlysheet/', AddMonthlySheetView.as_view(), name='add_monthlysheet'),
    path('monthlysheet/<int:pk>/', views.monthly_sheet_detail, name='monthly_sheet_detail'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Browser console:
[image]

Comment: This line looks suspicious in your `save()` method: `self.pk = f"{self.month}.{self.year}"`. `pk` (primary key) is usually an integer, and must be unique. I would suggest to comment out this line and try to test your app then.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't make any difference at all. 

What is mind-boggling is that there are no error messages at all, so I have no idea where to look.